# AUCTeX's C-c C-c gives multiple of latexmk options

Tags: emacs, auctex, latexmk

I am using Emacs 25.3 on OS X El capitan. When I do <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> to compile the `.tex` document I get the following prompt. Every one of these options actually run `latexmk` but somehow it bothers me that there are lots of prompts of the same name. Also, `synctex` sometimes stops working. What is going on here?. Should I ask this on `emacs stackexchange`?

[image]

**Edit after Arash Esbati's comment**: Here is my complete `AUCTeX` configuration.

```lisp
;; AucTeX configuration
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)

;; Use Skim as viewer, enable source <-> PDF sync
;; make latexmk available via C-c C-c
;; Note: SyncTeX is setup via ~/.latexmkrc (see below)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (push
    '("latexmk" "latexmk -pdf %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
      :help "Run latexmk on file")
    TeX-command-list)))
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (setq TeX-command-default "latexmk")))

;; use Skim as default pdf viewer
;; Skim's displayline is used for forward search (from .tex to .pdf)
;; option -b highlights the current line; option -g opens Skim in the background  
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Viewer")))
(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("PDF Viewer" "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline -b %n %o %b")))
```

Here is my `.latexmkrc` configuration

```
$recorder = 1;
$pdf_mode = 1;        # tex -> pdf
$pdf_previewer = 'open -a Skim  %O %S';
$bibtex_use = 2;
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape  %O %S';
@generated_exts = (@generated_exts, 'synctex.gz');
$clean_ext = 'synctex.gz synctex.gz(busy) run.xml tex.bak bbl bcf fdb_latexmk run tdo %R-blx.bib';
print("Config file located at $HOME/.latexmkrc\n");
```

Comment: This is a totally appropriate question. I would include a mwe also.

Comment: Well, a MWE is not practical here because this in my opinion, has nothing to do with LaTeX markup. It has something to do with `latexmk` and how it is working internally with `emacs`.

Comment: Well just because I would do it doesn't make it right for you. Best of luck troubleshooting the problems.

Comment: AUCTeX doesn't support `latexmk` out of the box.  How did you make it available to AUCTeX?  What's the value of the variable `TeX-command-list`?

Comment: When I try to do `M-x TeX-command-list` there is no such option. I have edited my question and added my `AucTeX` configuration and `latexmkrc` configuration above.

Comment: Found it. `TeX-command-list` has several entries for `latexmk`. I guess that's the reason why. I will remove the duplicate entries and report back here. Don't know how this happened.

Comment: I removed the multiple entries and now `C-c C-c` works clean. :). If you write that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you put your `latexmk` entry into `TeX-command-list` with the function `push`.  It does not check if an entry is already there and just adds it.  Hence, an entry is added each time `LaTeX-mode-hook` is called.  You can fix this by using `add-to-list` instead of `push`:

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
                         '("latexmk" "latexmk -pdf %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
                           :help "Run latexmk on file"))))
```

In general, you can check the value of a variable with <kbd>M-x describe-variable RET *var-name* RET</kbd> or <kbd>C-h v *var-name* RET</kbd> for short.